# Как авторизоваться в phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

При входе в `phpmyadmin`, просить логин и пароль. Откуда его брать? Я новичок, объясните, пожалуйста по подробнее.

Comment: Пароль брать у администратора mysql, само собой.

Comment: если ubuntu тогда по `/etc/dbconfig-common` есть файл `phpmyadmin.conf` и в нем записаны логин и пароль. При желании можно изменить их.

Answer (score 13):

Логин: **root**
Пароль: **root**

Или:

Логин: **mysql**
Пароль: **mysql**

Ну или иногда еще так

Логин: **root**
Пароль пустой

А вообще, phpMyAdmin спрашивает доступы к вашей базе данных.
Соответственно логин и пароль нужно указывать для созданного пользователя БД.
Или стандартные, которые я указал выше.

**Если выдает ошибку**

> 2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Отредактируйте файл **phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**, заменив вот эту строчку:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

на вот эту:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Полный листинг

```
<?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'ba17c1ec07d65003'; // use here a value of your choice
$i=0; $i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307'; // MySQL port
?>
```

Возможно, вы отредактировали конфигурационный файл MySQL, чтобы он запускался на другом порту. В этом случае, новый порт нужно указать и в конфигурационном файле phpMyAdmin (см. последнюю строчку из листинга выше).

Кроме того, сам конфигурационный файл **config.inc.php**, должен лежать в корневой папке phpMyAdmin.

Перед стартом phpMyAdmin MySQL уже должен быть запущен. Проверьте, есть ли соответствующий процесс в диспетчере задач.

Проверьте, есть ли у пользователя, от имени которого вы пытаетесь авторизоваться, соответствующие права.

Если все вышеперечисленное не помогло, возможно, сам MySQL криво встал. Попробуйте его переустановить.

Comment: >2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server вот эту ошибку выводит

Comment: @aaabbbccc, я обновил свой ответ

Comment: <?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'ba17c1ec07d65003'; // use here a value of your choice
$i=0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
?>
вот мой файл config.inc.php

Comment: @aaabbbccc, значит, добавьте указанную строку перед **?>**

Comment: опишите как полностью должен выглядеть файл config.inc.php

Comment: @aaabbbccc, как-то так:  

    <?php
    $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'ba17c1ec07d65003'; // use here a value of your choice
    $i=0; $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
    ?>

Comment: Все тоже самая ошибка

Comment: @aaabbbccc, я обновил свой ответ. Пожалуйста, укажите еще и тип вашей операционной системы, на которой наблюдается проблема.

Answer (score 5):

В убунту делаем так:

```
$ cd /etc/mysql/
$ sudo vim debian.cnf
```

И вот ответ :

> Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint     //Это пользователь
password = uTjAXFyQFsySSJOZ     //Это пароль

socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock<br>
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint     //Это пользователь
password = uTjAXFyQFsySSJOZ     //Это пароль
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 2):

Мне помогла вот эта вещь в настройках:
Логин: root
Пароль пустой

Благодарю