# Как подключить phpMyAdmin к сайту?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Решил изучать PHP, возникла необходимость в базе данных. 
Как подключить её к локальному серверу?

домен.ru/phpmyadmin - не работает

Comment: Если папка точно есть, попробуйте посмотреть, как она называется... Или введите phpMyAdmin, вдруг поможет

Comment: какой локальный сервер вы используете ?

Comment: Open Server 5.2.2

Comment: А что вы к чему подключаете ? phpmyadmin это не база данных, это визуальный интерфейс для работы с базой данных mysql. сама БД mysql должна быть установлена и настроена отдельно

Answer (score 1):

Может кому-нибудь пригодится

Перейти по ссылке - http://127.0.0.1/openserver/phpmyadmin/index.php (может быть другой)
Залогинится - [Как авторизоваться в phpMyAdmin?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/329649/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-phpmyadmin)
Подключение - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnrhmV0M8Zo

Comment: Просто совет от себя. Для локальной работы HeidiSQL (https://www.heidisql.com/) намного удобнее phpMyAdmin, если используешь OpenServer, то он у тебя также уже есть (в меню Система -> Разное -> MySQL менеджер). Подключение настраиваешь пользователю root с пустым паролем к хосту 127.0.0.1