# Не могу зайти в phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Скачал архив с официального сайта phpmyadmin, распаковал его в корневую директорию моего веб-сервера, захожу по ссылке my.domain/phpmyadmin у меня высвечивается поля для авторизации. Но когда я ввожу свой пароль от пользователя root моей MariaDB, то никакой авторизации не происходит, никаких ошибок не пишет. Что я должен сделать, что бы я мог зайти phpmyadmin?

Comment: `никаких ошибок не пишет` — не может быть. по умолчанию сервер баз данных должен ошибки записывать в лог-файл.

Comment: Может это поможет? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/329649/

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB не позволяет авторизоваться откуда угодно как root (кроме root shell). Просто создайте другого пользователя и сделайте его супер администратором.

В ракушке: sudo mysql
Затем

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Предоставить все разрешения

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;